# If an npm package ships with multiple dist folders, how do I know which one is used when my App is built?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack, aurelia

I am using an npm package (`aurelia-google-maps`) in my application. The package ships with AMD, System, CommonJS, Native Modules, and ES2015 dist folders like this:

```
/node_modules/
    /aurelia-google-maps/
        /dist/
            /amd
            /system
            /native-modules
            /es2015
            /commonjs
```

In my typescript app I am simply importing all the classes and functions as:

```js
import {Configure} from "aurelia-google-maps"
```

Is there a way that I can find out which distribution is used when I build my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. It seems like Aurelia automatically registers it's own plugin called DistPlugin that resolves dependencies using the `native-modules` folder. See [this](https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/wiki/AureliaPlugin-options) wiki for an explanation on how to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can determine it without the help of your build tool. It can be done in 2 steps:

- using type of to check the availability of a variable in runtime code:

```
const distType = typeof DIST_TYPE !== 'undefined' ? DIST_TYPE : void 0;
```

- configure the build tool to replace `DIST_TYPE` with the distribution target

And then you can use it in normal code, via `distType` variable.

---

For typescript, you just need an extra declaration

```
declare const DIST_TYPE: string | undefined;
```